# detecting vertical mouse motion on a horizontal slider

Tags: wpf, slider

I'm using a horizontal slider in WPF, but would like to also perform some action if the mouse is moved vertically (like change the brightness of some control).

I tried responding to MouseMove, but I don't get an update when dragging the slider, if the mouse moves purely vertically - my function only gets called when the slider actually moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach a handler to the slider's [PreviewMouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousemove.aspx) event.